# Running a old version of Jar-file

Tags: java, jar, error-handling

I am creating a server-client application and I have a problem. I'm running my server on a remote computer and trying to connect from another. I can connect, and my server lets me know that a client have connected. However I have a error where if two clients connects and one try to write something, he kills the other client for some reason. Now this is the problem. I wanted to see why that happend so I fixed some code in my program did a **"Clean and Build Project"** with no error

I figured out that maybe it had something to do with my input from `DataInputStream` so I wanted to see if I recieved any data from the Inputstream, because the error I recieve is `java.io.EOFException` and `java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort<Unknown Source>`

Changing my method from

```
while (Connected) {
            MessageReply(IN.readUTF());                
        }
```

To

```
while (Connected) {
            //MessageReply(IN.readUTF());
            System.out.println(IN.readUTF());
        }
```

After I changed the code I did a **"Clean and Build Project"** with no error, BUT for some reason when I execute my JAR-file it still keeps doing what the function `MessageReply(IN.readUTF());` is supposed to do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check that behaviour with a debugger or do you _guess_ that?

Comment: I am guessing. When I tried to do this "local" then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the deployment might not have worked (maybe you have not transmitted the file to your server correctly?). Also, I personnally like to rename a method, rebuild the jar, unzip the jar, open the .class file in a text editor. You won't be able to read it, but you should be able to find the renamed method name. This will tell you if you have the right version of the code.

Comment: Yeah I did that in Notepad++ and in the .class file it shows that the method `ReplyMessage` is a comment instead of a working method. Still doesn't work.